# If someone is in a conversion process are they required to break shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, conversion-to-judaism

If someone is in the middle of an orthodox conversion do they HAVE to break shabbat?

Comment: See: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62441/8775, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28947/8775, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20585/why-shouldnt-gentiles-keep-shabbat, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18995/can-a-gentile-go-to-synagogue-on-shabbat-and-what-is-forbidden-on-shabbat-for-a, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13447/8775.

Comment: What do you "middle of an Orthodox conversion"? Like after circumcision but before dipping in the Mikvah?

Comment: If you are still studying for conversion, but have not yet gone through the full process, then you are not Jewish and are required to perform at least one *melacha* on shabbat. The rabbi that you are studying with will explain this to you. There are some who say that only Jews have the day *sunset to sunrise* and nonJews can consider the day midnight to midnight (or possibly sunrise to sunrise). In that case, they can perform an action Friday during the day and Saturday night after the time for havdallah. Other people will keep something like a pen in an inner pocket of their jacket. CYLOR

Comment: Basically as Sabahillel says, But make sure to clear with your Rabbi exactly which Melachos count! For example, a pen on you will only be effective if you are in an area with no Eruv. Or, as a different example, lighting a match for no purpose other than to "break" Shabbos would not actually accomplish anything!

Comment: possible duplicate of ... http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13447/is-it-a-discouraged-or-an-unacceptable-practice-for-a-gentile-to-keep-the-sabbat/13448#13448