# Blessing on Shabbat candle lighting for men

Tags: halacha, shabbat, blessing, men-male, candle-lighting

Should a man say the blessing then light the shabbos candles or light the candles first then say the blessing?

Comment: All Mitzvot have their blessings made before the action (Megillah 21b).

Comment: You're asking specifically about a man, so I'm guessing you suspect it might be different than for a woman.  Could you [edit] in what you already know about this?  (I think I know why, but I'm not you.)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Please [edit your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/5102) to give yourself a name. I hope you'll look around the site and find other enlightening information, perhaps including our 659 other [tag:shabbat] questions. Finally, don't miss [*Purim - Mi Yodeya?*](http://s.tk/miyodeya)!

Answer (score 6):

The Sefer Piskei Tshuvos siman 263:10 writes that if a man lights he makes the bracha first because he is not mekabel shabbas with his lighting(unless he wants to take shabbas in with lighting,then he should light first).

See footnote 32 which brings sources such as Eishel Avraham and the Aruch Hashulchan seif 13,there is an opnion brought in the footnote which holds one should light one light then make the bracha and then finish with the rest of the lights but it does not seem to be the minhag.

Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky in Kovetz Halachos perek 7:42 writes that the man makes the bracha first.In the footnote there is an interesting psak from the [Derech Hachaim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42756&st=&pgnum=303) who holds that it is a lo plug and even a man lights first.However Rav Shmuel paskens like the Biur Halacha who says that a man says bracha first.