# The single male and shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, blessing, men-male, candle-lighting

Is a single male permitted to light the shabbat candles and say the blessing? And if so, how many candles? Do the rules change based on whether alone or in the company any single females?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10961/husband-lighting-shabbat-candles

Comment: Welcome to [Mi Yodeya](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/about), Fireman Rob, and thanks for bringing your question here! Please note that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends. On another note, might I suggest you check out [our Passover _seder_ supplement for print](http://s.tk/miyodeya)?

Comment: Yes, and he must. He must even add additional candles for the weeks he misses. Not sure if the starting number is one or two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Men and women are both obligated in the Mitzva of Shabbat candles and saying the blessing. Women have precedence to ensure the Mitzva is fulfilled because they are more often at home preparing the house on Friday afternoon. (Shulchan Aruch OC 263:2-5 and *Mishne Torah, Hilchos shabas* ch. 5)

Comment: Thanks! So for clarity, when you say women have "precedence", would it be acceptable, even in mixed company for a male to light and recite just because? For instance, if the woman of the house simply deferred, "no you go ahead and do it tonight"? We often celebrate with miscellaneous guests and it's nice for everyone to have a chance to participate.

Comment: If the women give permission i see no reason to object. You should check with your Rabbi who understands the particulars of your situation for a final ruling though.